# How do I uninstall McAfee antivirus from Mac

Tags: mac, uninstall

I need to uninstall expired McAfee Total Protection from my Mac. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you run the [uninstaller](https://service.mcafee.com/webcenter/faces/oracle/webcenter/page/scopedMD/s55728c97_466d_4ddb_952d_05484ea932c6/Page29.jspx?articleTitle=McAfee+KB+-+Comment+installer+et+d%C3%A9sinstaller+McAfee+Internet+Security+for+Mac+%28TS101226%29&locale=en-US&_adf.ctrl-state=uk6x4ox8k_9&wc.contextURL=%2Fspaces%2Fcp&articleId=TS101226&_afrLoop=240844225954236#!)?

Comment: In MAC there is no uninstaller

Comment: There should be an uninstaller in Applications.  If you don't have the uninstaller you could reinstall McAfee and then run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I had to uninstall McAfee is I took a different version McAfee Livesafe, Earlier I used McAfee Total Protection.

Initially I thought that I need to uninstall the [McAfee Total protection](https://www.mcafee.com/consumer/en-us_multi/spromos/sem/m1487/mtp_537.html?cid=238414&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=paidsearch&utm_campaign=en-us:Search:Brand&utm_content=en-us:Search:Brand&utm_term=mcafee%20total%20protection%20download&msclkid=06521cf8256316a9bce0415dedb74fbf) and then install [McAfee Livesafe](https://www.mcafee.com/consumer/en-us/store/m0/catalog/mls_430/mcafee-livesafe.html).

But when I attempted to install [McAfee Livesafe](https://www.mcafee.com/consumer/en-us/store/m0/catalog/mls_430/mcafee-livesafe.html), the installer prompted me that the installer itself will uninstall the previous version.

But for someone, who wanted to Uninstall [McAfee Total protection](https://www.mcafee.com/consumer/en-us_multi/spromos/sem/m1487/mtp_537.html?cid=238414&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=paidsearch&utm_campaign=en-us:Search:Brand&utm_content=en-us:Search:Brand&utm_term=mcafee%20total%20protection%20download&msclkid=06521cf8256316a9bce0415dedb74fbf), please refer to https://www.knockit.me/blogs/mac/uninstall-mcafee-from-mac-os

**Steps:**
[Images showing two locations for Library on Mac OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CNgy.png)

As shown in the above image, there are two locations named Library on your computer, both these locations are used to store the preferences and supporting files of the programs. The first Library folder is at the top level and the second Library folder is inside your User Folder. To completely uninstall a software, it is very important to remove items from both these locations.

Next, remove any similarly named items you find inside the User Library inside your User Folder ~/Library in the same set of folders:

~/Library
~/Library/Application Support
~/Library/LaunchAgents
~/Library/Preferences
~/Library/PreferencePanes
~/Library/StartupItems

When deleting something from an installation, I'd always take a backup of the files I've removed, then I would restart the machine to see if everything looks good and then delete the backed up files.

Comment: Your answer just provides the solution on an external site. Please post the required steps here, on our site, so that future readers don't have to go somewhere else. Ideally you can add a quote for the most relevant parts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall, just open Finder and got to the Applications folder. From there you'll be able to see all of your applications that are installed. Find McAfee and drag it to the trash can and then empty the trash can to remove the application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know but after researching for couple hours I've found that uninstallation of applications like McAfee, Symantic is not straight forward.